# Typo3 redirect domain with prefix to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3, realurl

I am using Typo3 with RealUrl and theres following i want:
**foo.domain.com** should redirect to **www.otherdomain.com**

I tried it with domain records in Typo3 (theres a redirect option) and .htaccess stuff but nothing seems to work.

Every prefix i try **foo.domain.com** or **bar.domain.com** redirects me to **domain.com**

Any ideas?

Heres the .htaccess in case you want to take a look:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bli.bla\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bla.bli.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www1.bla.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www5.bla.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This example works 100% if implementet right. (TYPO3 .htaccess: "# Add your own rules here.")
Maybe you should delete Cooluri or Realurl Cached links.

Comment: doesnt work (maybe becouse of realurl?) bli.bla.com redirects me to bla.com instead bla.bli.com

Comment: Please, use the code formatting. Your answer is currently really hard to read.

Comment: there are no cached realUrl pathes for the page where the wrong redirect happens also for the destination. tried both of your snippets after the "# Add your own rules here." line. :( still the same problem.

Comment: add it right after RewriteEngine On. This has nothing to do with RealURL, not even with TYPO3 - it's just .htaccess business

Comment: i accept this as answer.. the problem was another file which overwrites my RewriteRules -.-